# why does this code not allow me to continue? it is a movement script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public float moveForce = 10f;

    [SerializeField]
    public float jumpForce = 11f;

    private float movementX;

    private Ridgidbody2D myBody;

    private SpriteRenderer sr;

    private Animator anim;
    private string WALK_ANIMATION = "walk";

    private void Awake();
    {
        myBody.AddForce(new Vector2)2, 2));
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    
    }

} // class
```

This code is meant to be my player movement code, i have followed a tutorial and everything seems about right but i do not understand what is wrong about it. i would be grateful if anyone could help

Comment: What do you expect to happen. On waking its given a nudge. And thats all the code here does.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that the awake method will be called once; at the very beginning of the game.

If i am going to talk about "movement" that you wrote, there is no input taking nor, defining. You have to define those, then utilize them in the [update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) or [fixed-update](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) (for physics calculations) method. Make sure that you are starting with a small project.

Answer (score 0):

Move the following lines to Update() function

```
myBody.AddForce(new Vector2)2, 2));
anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
```

Awake runs once when the object is created, and not on every frame.